# Weblogic 12C configuration of connection factory target

Tags: jms, weblogic, cluster-computing, load-balancing, target

I have 2 managed servers instances, 2 machines, 2 jms servers and I have 1 instances on each machine. 
There are a cluster for my 2 instances but i notice in my configuration of my queues and connection factory, they have an error. The target is not on cluster but on my jms server, like this :
TARGET => JMSs1,JMSs2

Does load balancing and failover work even if the target is not the cluster and even if on my connection factoy, the load balancing is enabled ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What type of queues you have created? UDD or Queue?

Comment: Hello, i have created Uniform Distributed Queue.

Comment: Then Load Balancing should happen as expected

Answer (score 0):

If the UDD queues are configured then Load Balancing will happen as expected.